# MimeKit Iterator with FileStreams

Tags: c#, filestream, mime, mimekit

I just managed to rewrite some code that should now manage to process large MIME files meant for printing.

For this we used MimeKit in the following manner:

```
        var message = MimeMessage.Load(_fileStream, true);
        var iter = new MimeIterator(message);
        while (iter.MoveNext())
        {
        ...
        }
```

What is interesting here is that before I used fileStream, we used to copy the inputStream of a HttpListenerRequest object, which is a NetworkStream (non-seekable) which can not be loaded to MimeKit.

Since adding fileStream, for a 2GB job, I spend around 40 seconds inside the while loop iterating for each part of the request which is a lot if you ask me... with memoryStream it was 6 seconds.

Is this behavior normal? Is there ca chance to get better times with MimeKit or should I implement my own parser?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> What is interesting here is that before I used fileStream, we used to copy the inputStream of a HttpListenerRequest object, which is a NetworkStream (non-seekable) which can not be loaded to MimeKit.

I'm not quite sure what you mean above. Were you doing something like this?

```
var memory = new MemoryStream ();
httpResponse.Stream.CopyTo (memory);
memory.Position = 0;
var message = MimeMessage.Load(memory, true);
```

> Since adding fileStream, for a 2GB job, I spend around 40 seconds inside the while loop iterating for each part of the request which is a lot if you ask me... with memoryStream it was 6 seconds.

Your use of `MimeMessage.Load()` passes `true` as the `persistent` argument. This improves *parsing* performance (because it no longer needs to load MIME content into RAM after parsing), but negatively impacts performance of reading the content of individual MIME parts later because it needs to seek to the `_fileStream` starting offset for the content of each MIME part as you request it.

> Is this behavior normal?

40 seconds does seem like a lot, but without knowing more details of your code, I can't make any suggestions.

> Is there a chance to get better times with MimeKit or should I implement my own parser?

Well, I can pretty much guarantee that if you implement your own parser, it will very likely be orders of magnitude slower than MimeKit (seeing as how literally every other attempt to write a MIME parser in C# is orders of magnitude slower than MimeKit) ;-)

What you need to do here is run your code under a profiler to see where the problem is.

If the performance problem is as you suggest inside of the loop, it is NOT a performance problem in the parser. It is a performance problem within your loop. That's not to say that MimeKit code doesn't play a role in the slowness.

If the problem is in MimeKit, I would suspect this logic inside of BoundStream.Read():

```
// make sure that the source stream is in the expected position
if (BaseStream.Position != StartBoundary + position)
    BaseStream.Seek (StartBoundary + position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

In your case, `BaseStream` should be your `_fileStream`. It's been a while since I've looked at the code for `FileStream.Position`, but it *may* require a syscall to get that value (and syscalls are not free).

40 seconds, though, is a LOT of time - way more than I would expect unless each MIME part's content is massive (streaming content of a MimePart.Content will read ~4K per loop and if there is 1 lseek() per loop, that can add up).

Hope that helps you figure this out.

Comment: Hello,  I did a little bit of extra debugging with a profiler in order to see what exactly happens. Some problems i did manage to fix that were from my code that was running in the loop. After fixing those I was happy with the result but I found some sporadic behavior while doing DecodeTo method...

Comment: Same 2GB file sometimes  is decoded in below 30 seconds and some times above 60s... I can't get a hold of the issue that makes this so unstable. Is this a known isssue or something that maybe im doing wrong on my side? Every time I use DecodeTo is to decode data to a filestream and save it to disk.  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Off-hand, I'm not sure what would cause that (as far as code in MimeKit). 2GB is a lot of data and it may just be due to kernel-space switching. I'd be interested in knowing if you are able to debug this further and figure out what is going on.

Comment: @jsteadfast i've been debugging for the last couple of days and the only thing that i managed to find was the Cache memory that was getting above 10GB and would slow down the performance. What I noticed works for me best is to use Open instead of DecodeTo and do something like Open.CopyTo . As far as you know is it safe to use Open?

Comment: I thought I had responded to this already but apparently I didn't. Yes, it is safe to use `Open()` instead of `DecodeTo()`. I don't understand how/why it would make a difference, though.

Comment: Actually... CopyTo() by default uses a 16K buffer size whereas MimeKit's DecodeTo() uses a 4K buffer size, so this *may* make Open().CopyTo() faster than DecodeTo(), but it shouldn't use any less memory than DecodeTo().

Comment: do you know if there is a possibility to adjust the buffer used by DecodeTo?

Comment: There is not, no.I suppose I could add an argument to DecodeTo to allow specifying a buffer size, but it hasn't really been an issue (other than *maybe* this case).

Comment: A buffer would make sense only when working with bigger data, for mail stuff i suppose it wouldnt matter, but in printing, when you have mime files larger than 2gb it will help improving performance.